# How to log out other session when changed password in Coldfusion

Tags: session, authentication, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

It has recently come to my attention that a user may log into the site using two different browsers e.g. Chrome and FireFox.  When he changes the password using Chrome, the FireFox session should also log out. Right now it doesn't.

I am using ColdFusion cookies and session variables for logins.  How can one detect and kick out the other session (the one that didn't make the password change)?  How can this be done using ColdFusion?

Comment: You could use websockets and when a user logs out, you could send a message to that user’s channel.

Comment: You can write the timestamp of the log in into the session and a database. When these don't match, log them out.

Comment: What version of CF are you using? That could influence what options you have.

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno I am using CF10.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler Do you mean a timestamp of login into session and database and change the timestamp when password changed?

Answer (score 0):

If you track password changes, you could put a `passwordLastUpdated` key in session. If a session does not contain that key, then log it out. If you also keep a `loginTimestamp` in session, you can check if the current login session is after `passwordLastUpdated` and force a new login as well.

You should track password changes, with the hashes of a user's previous 3 or so passwords to make sure they're not reusing recent passwords.

**Clarification:**

In the DB, you should be tracking when a user's password was last changed. Add that value to a new key the ColdFusion session data when a user logs in. If your `user` data is stored in `session.user`, then create a new key:

```
session.user.passwordLastUpdated
```

Now, in `onRequestStart` or wherever you check that a user has a valid session, also check

```
<cfset bValidSession = true>
<cfif !structKeyExists(session.user, "passwordLastUpdated">
    <cfset bValidSession = false>
<cfelse>
    <!--- 
        if the timestamp in passwordLastUpdated
        is newer than then time when the user last logged in.
    --->
    <cfset bValidSession = false>
</cfif>
<cfif !bValidSession>
    <!--- Do your log out process. --->
</cfif>
```

The session in the other browser will not have this key in `session.user` and it will be logged out at the next request.

Comment: *if the current login session is after passwordLastUpdated* So each request would check the database (not the session variable) to determine when the password was last changed - and force a logout if needed? (I wasn't sure which "passwordLastUpdated" you were was referring to in that last sentence :-).

Comment: ^^^ Clarified answer

Comment: @AdrianJMoreno - Maybe I need more caffeine, but ... don't you need more than session variables? Since the sessions are separate, once they're both logged in, session B wouldn't know the password was changed on session A unless it retrieved that information from another database call. What am I missing? :-)

Comment: @Ageax Session A in Browser 1, Session B in Browser 2. Session A changes password, gets new key `passwordLastUpdated`. Session B hits a new page, checks for key which doesn't exist, fails and gets kicked out. BUT I can see where the 2nd scenario fails if both have the new key and one changes password.

Comment: I could have sworn there's a way to see all active sessions on an instance. You could then check for a common piece of info, like login email and invalidate all of those sessions on the server .

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno Maybe I am missing something.  If Session B hits a new page,  wouldn't he have the old 'passwordLastUpdated' key in his session when he first login? Probably I have to check this old session key with the password change date in the DB on every move?  Either that or I need a login timestamp session and check it against the password changed date in DB.  Check DB on every page is probably not practical.  But I don't know if there is a way when Session A change the password, CF somehow knows Session B belong to the same user and somehow kick Session B out?

Comment: @AdrianJMoreno - Maybe there's something new in CF2016+? The only method I know of is the old (proprietary) sessionTracker built into CF.